# Fixing data source of same layer in multiple MXDs?

Tags: arcpy, data-source

I have this one specific layer in a bunch of mxd files with a broken data source. I am working on a script to automate fixing the data source. I am having trouble getting it to loop through a folder and fix the layer on all mxd files in that same folder.

This is the script I have so far:

```
#Import modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

#Put file path for the folder containing mxds, where I have my sample file path
env.workspace = r"G:\Geomatics\Map Requests\2017-07-24_TrailClosures"

#Looping through all mxd documents, list layers and replace those layers MRGTrails layer with proper data source
for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(file)
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames("*.mxd", "Layers")[0]
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
      if lyr.name == "Trails":
        lyr.replaceDataSource(r'G:\Geomatics\Data\Regional\MRG.gdb', "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", "Trails_Sentiers", validate=False)

    mxd.save()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What is the specific question that you have?

Answer (score 2):

You had a few minor typos. Honestly, this question will probably get closed for being unique to your particular set of mistakes. But here's a solution, with comments describing changes from the original:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\Geomatics\Map Requests\2017-07-24_TrailClosures"

for file in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(file) # Changed 'files' to file
    # Iterate over all data frames, because what if one has a different name...or if a map has multiple data frames
    # And pass the mxd object to the function--not the mxd wildcard
    for df in arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd):
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):
            if lyr.name == "Trails":
                lyr.replaceDataSource(r'G:\Geomatics\Data\Regional\MRG.gdb', "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", "Trails_Sentiers", validate=False)
    mxd.save()
```